# Get table inside an html comment with python

Tags: python, html

I am trying to parse a webpage that has a table inside a comment. I can't seem to figure out how to get the columns and data of the table out of the comment. Here's part of the html source:

```html
<div id="all_info" class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented">
    <div class="section_heading">
       <span class="section_anchor" id="id_link" data-label="interesting data"/>
       <h2>blah, blah</h2>    
       <div class="section_heading_text">
           <ul> <li>* indicates something important</li></ul>
       </div>              
    </div>
    <div class="placeholder"/>
    <!--  
        <div class="table_outer_container">
        <div class="overthrow table_container" id="div_info">
        <table class="sortable stats_table" id="info" data-cols-to-freeze=1>    <caption>Interesting data Table</caption>
            <colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr class="over_header"> <td> these are discard filler headers</td>
                </tr>
                <tr> <td> there are multiple entries here for headers </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ><td> Lots of data here in series of columns </td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    -->
</div>
```

I am using PyQuery but am open to other solutions. So far I get a PyQuery document from the html as follows:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import requests

doc = pq(requests.get(url).content)
table = doc('#all_info')
```

That gets me the PyQuery object with the text I showed above. I also found etree which I can use to isolate the comment text, but then I lose the ability to isolate html markup in the text. Here's that code:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(str(table))
comments = tree.xpath('//comment()')
for c in comments:
    print c
```

As a note, there's only one comment in each comment list.

Does anyone have other ideas on a better way to approach this? One thought I have is to just remove the comment markup and treat everything in the comment as just valid html. But I couldn't figure out how to do that and keep my ability to use PyQuery to find objects. I am open to using Soup or others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is indeed only one comment per document, simply remove it before passing the string to `BeautifulSoup` or whatever you use for parsing:

```
doc = doc.replace("<!--","").replace("-->","")
```

Comment: You were right, I was so close to just answering this one on my own.

`comment = etree.tostring(comments[0])`,
`contents = comment.replace("<!--","").replace("-->","")`,
`table = pq(contents)`.

Thanks!